# Force 404 redirect to home?

Tags: redirect, 404-error

normally with a 404 error the site will be redirected to theme/404.php. I'd like to the home page instead. I tried

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com
```

but it doesn't work. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: A redirection with a 404 status code doesn't exist. Also, the file 404.php from a WordPress theme is the template loaded for requests that return a 404 status, no redirection to 404.php file occurs. I think you are confused about what HTTP status codes are and the difference with redirections.

Answer (score 2):

A 404 should never be a redirect. A redirection status begins with `3`, not with `4`.

You can either include the `index.php` (or `home.php` or `front-page.php`) in your `404.php` or just remove the `404.php` from your theme. Then WordPress [will use the `index.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/c50acdcb4c0b09d6f060166cc4a3a5ffc326dbf1/wp-includes/template-loader.php#L58).

Comment: It's false that removing the `404.php` file will show the `index.php`. Have you tried it?

Comment: @DanielMuñozParsapoormoghadam See the link in my answer: When no `404.php` has been found, `index.php` is used.

Comment: Do you really understand the code you are linking there? Because below of `if (is_404() && $template = get_404_template()):` there is a fantastic `elseif` calling the `get_search_template()` function, which will return you a 404 error, again, since it's not finding the string you are supposedly searching. And yes, I tried it.

Comment: @DanielMuñozParsapoormoghadam you are totally wrong. See the link in the answer again and study the code carefully.

Comment: @DanielMuñozParsapoormoghadam The `elseif` matches only on search pages. This is never `true` on a 404 page. Quite the opposite: a search without matches results in a 404.

Comment: Looking into the 'all-404-redirect-to-homepage' plugin, it's not that linear, indeed.